# I have an XML string from a SOAP web service using __getLastResponse method, how can I get the substring of an XML string?

Tags: php

I have an XML string from a SOAP web service using __getLastResponse method, how can I get the substring of an XML string ?

Comment: What do you mean by "substring of an XML string"?  Chances are, the solution here is to use an XML parser.

Comment: Hello Rocket Hazmat,
When you use the getLastResponse() method, the return value is an XML string.

Comment: Yes.  So, then you just need to throw it into an XML parser (like SimpleXML) and get what you need.

Comment: How do I throw that into an XML parser ?
I tried to use SimpleXML, but I don't think I used it in a right way.

Comment: You take the XML string, and do `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($yourXMLString);`  Then you can get whatever you wanted out of the XML.  What does your XML look like and what are you trying to get out of it?  Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php  Example: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: This is the XML string ...
1258861746091904258867018711746091904FevenAhadufalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalse00falsefalse00false00falsefalse0000000false-999-99900-17018711746091904FevenAhadufalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalse00falsefalse00false00falsefalse0000000false-999-99900

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26264993/edit) your question and add that there.  Also, add which value you are trying to get.

Comment: And, the XML file from SOAP XML call ... just part of it

<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><NewDataSet xmlns=""><RT diffgr:id="RT1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><Ret_Code>1</Ret_Code><TenantID>25887</TenantID><AccessCode>372631936</AccessCode></RT><Tenants diffgr:id="Tenants1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="modified"><TenantID>25887</TenantID><SiteID>7018</SiteID><EmployeeID>71</EmployeeID>